# AndroidPlot 1.x change range label formatting

Tags: androidplot

I'm trying to set the range value format (Y-axis) of my plot to not show any decimals. In versions prior to 1.x you could apparently set the format by using `plot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));` but this method is not available in the newest version.

How can I do this in the newest version of AndroidPlot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.x you'd do this:

```
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT).setFormat(new DecimalFormat("#"));
```

For background, the change in 1.x was part of a larger set of changes to enable support for arbitrarily applying labels on any of the 4 edges of the screen, as opposed to only the bottom and left edges.